# How can I use Python to interact with a command line multiple times without losing instance specific variables like working directory?

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I am trying to simulate a command prompt inside of my program (like the one at the bottom of VS Code, for example).

Here is what I have tried:

```
import os

while(True):
    console_command = input()
    console_stream = os.popen(console_command)
    console_output = console_stream.read()
    print(console_output)
```

This almost works, but current directory and other runtime specific data is lost because os.popen opens a new instance of the terminal every time it calls a command. Most importantly, it is impossible to use the cd command to change directories when using this implementation.

I have also considered storing each time the user calls a command that changes directory and appending these calls to the front of any commands the user runs, but this seems like a bad idea because it can cause errors if the user modifies the directory. It would also make my code very messy and it would take a lot of memory.

*Note - this is not a duplicate of other questions asking how to run a command in python because I need to run multiple commands in the same terminal and offer live responses. Combining multiple commands into a single line is not an option.*

Comment: Use the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to open the process and communicate with it. There are examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution 1 - use `subprocess`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import select
import os

shell = subprocess.Popen(["bash"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
poll = select.poll()  # To peek if there's stdout.
poll.register(shell.stdout, select.POLLIN)

while True:
    console_command = input('> ') + '\n'
    shell.stdin.write(str.encode(console_command))
    shell.stdin.flush()

    console_output = b''
    while True:
        has_output = poll.poll(50)  # If no new output within 50ms, we assume all the output is finished.
        if not has_output:
            break
        console_output += os.read(shell.stdout.fileno(), 4096)
    print(console_output.decode())
```

### Demo for Solution 1

```
> SOME_STRING=hello_stackoverflow

> echo $SOME_STRING
hello_stackoverflow

> pwd
/tmp

> cd ~/Documents

> pwd     
/Users/my_user_name/Documents
```

---

## Solution 2 - use `pexpect`

For this method, you will be interacting with a real shell. Just like the one at the bottom of VS Code.

```
import pexpect

shell = pexpect.spawn('sh')
shell.interact()
```

Comment: For anybody attempting to use this, note that it won't run on Windows (even after changing "bash" to "cmd") because select.poll() is not supported on Windows. 

Also note that it's not a perfect implementation. There are some minor issues with the assumption that all output is finished within a certain time period (such as when attempting to ping a website). I think a possible way to fix this is to use asyncio, but I am not sure.

Despite these issues this is by far the best solution I have seen on the internet. I tested it and it worked great. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You can do what the shell does and define some commands that are executed locally. One trick is to preface them with "!" to differentiate from commands that should be passed through.

```
import os

while(True):
    console_command = input()
    if console_command.startswith("!"):
        # do your parsing here. Here is a lame one
        scmd = console_command[1:].split()
        try:
            if scmd[0] == "cd":
                os.chdir(scmd[1])
            else:
                raise IndexError()
        except IndexError:
            print("invalid command")
        continue
       
    console_stream = os.popen(console_command)
    console_output = console_stream.read()
    print(console_output)
```